# Should I use or avoid Composer for non-PHP dependencies (like jQuery, CSS tools etc.)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, composer-php

### Question

Is there any official statement from the Composer creators that clearly recommends to use or to avoid Composer for JS/CSS/etc-dependencies too ?

#### Why I'm asking

Fetching JS/CSS-preprocessors etc. with Composer makes sense, but also seems hacky. Some of the big packages (Symfony etc.) are doing it too, they load jQuery, jQuery UI etc. via Composer, however the download numbers are quite low. But this is a clear "technology"-break, the JS-world has its own dependency management tools. There is (afaik) no official statement on the Composer site.

How do other server-side languages handle this ?

I'm searching for an official statement or the recommendation of somebody with deep knowledge of Composer / dependency management.

Comment: If you're looking for an "official" statement, you might do better asking on twitter using the #composer hashtag. This is also a pretty subjective question, so I don't think you'll get the kind of definitive answer you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my comment on your question, this is a pretty subjective question.  I don't think you're going to get the kind of answer you're looking for.  With that in mind, I think the fact there's a [2 year-old feature request still open](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/524) for managing front end dependencies is fairly authoritative.

IMHO, it comes down to the right tool for the job.  Bower does a good job managing front-end dependencies, while Composer shines managing PHP dependencies.  I avoid Composer for managing front-end dependencies.

FWIW, I don't know how "deep" my Composer knowledge is, but I've been using it for quite some time, feel comfortable with it, and have presented on it for php|architect.  Not an expert, perhaps, but close enough for government work.